# Lambda expression for multiple join tables with dynamic where clause

Tags: linq, dynamic, where-clause

Here is sample Linq statement:

```
var query = (from fm in db.table1
join fe in db.table2 on fm.Id equals fe.id                                     
where (fe.field1 >= 200)
select new { fm, fe });
```

So i need to write where clause "field1" Dynamically and also conditions(> , <, >=, <=) with constant value "200"

I am new to Web Api. any one please help in this.

Comment: First of all you should please add the code which you had tried. So, we can help. Answer to your question you need to use expression trees to generate the query. Read this - http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/expression-tree

Comment: @ManishM `string sfieldname = "field1";int countvalue = 200;
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(table2), "fe");
var member = Expression.Property(parameter, sfieldname);
var constant = Expression.Constant(countvalue);
var body = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(member, Expression.Convert(constant, member.Type));
var finalExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<table2, bool>>(body, parameter);
var query = (from fm in db.table1 join fe in db.table2 on fm.Id equals fe.id select new { fm, fe }); 

var data = query.where(finalExpression).select(o => o.fm);`

Comment: @ManishM This is code i tried. But Later i didn't get how to use that "finalExpression" in above "data" variable.